# Cannot get value from ADF component in fileDownloadActionListener

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, download, oracle-adf

I am facing a problem that I could not find any resolution for...
I have a selectManyChoice component like this:

```
<af:selectManyChoice value="#{bindings.my_VO1.inputValue}" 
                     label="myLabel" id="smc1"
                     binding="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.myMultiSelection}"
                     autoSubmit="true">
  <f:selectedItems value="#{bindings.my_VO1.items}" id="si1"/>
</af:selectManyChoice>
```

For getting out the values, I tested using 2 buttons like this:

```
<af:commandButton text="First Button" 
                  id="cb1" 
                  action="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.saveSelection}>
  <af:fileDownloadActionListener method="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.exportReport}"/>
</af:commandButton>
```

And:

```
<af:commandButton text="Second Button" 
                  id="cb2" 
                  action="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.saveSelection}/>
```

The second button could successfully get the selected values and print them out to the screen. However, the first button could not. It would always throw a NullPointerException when i tried to call myMultiSelection.getValue(), at this line of code:

```
public String saveSelection() {
    if (myMultiSelection.getValue() != null) {
```

The only difference between them is the fileDownloadActionListener tag. I wonder if that tag was affecting the inner works of the first button...However, I still need that tag, since the purpose of the button is to generate a pdf file based on the selected values, and have the browser download that file. Can anybody point me to the right direction?

Comment: Not sure if you copied right or wrong but you forget the closing " in your actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it this way :
Use your second button and in his actionlistener you just call the fileDownloadActionListener. That way you know for sure if the selected value is correct.

Example : http://adfwithejb.blogspot.be/2012/08/calling-affiledownloadactionlistener_2.html

**Edit:
Instead of using JS to call the actionlistener you can do it this way:**

Add these to your page :

```
<af:commandButton text="Hidden Button" binding="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.btnHiddenButton}"
                  id="cb1" visible="false">
  <af:fileDownloadActionListener method="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.exportReport}"/>
</af:commandButton>

<af:commandButton text="Visible Button" 
                  id="cb2" 
                  action="#{pageFlowScope.myBean.saveSelection}/>
```

Then in your bean, go to the saveSelection method and do some stuff the get your correct data.
After that add this :

```
ActionEvent event = new ActionEvent(btnHiddenButton);
event.queue();
```

This will trigger the hidden button without pressing it. (make sure you have a binding of course)

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked. I wonder if using javascript for something so simple like this will leave an impact to the system performance or not. Is there not any other way of using native ADF libraries to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Not really since it only activates an actionlistener.

Comment: @hoangbv15 Check out the edited solution. You should be able to avoid the JS with the second method.